# While-loop keeps crashing in Google Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a question!

I want to detect something on a website, but everytime I try this with a while-loop the tab is freezing. I tried to make the while-loop slower, but the tab is freezing everytime. It is a client side script for Google Chrome just to detect one of 4 states. The states are diffrent times. Can you please help me?

*Sorry for my bad english and not much knowledge about scripting/ programming :)

Default code without the timings:

```
while (running) {
fullStatus = checkStatus()
switch (fullStatus.substring(0, 2)) {
  case "**":
    rolled = true;
    status = 1;
    console.log("Rolling")
    break;

  case "Ro":
    status = 2;
    console.log("Prepare Bets")
    break;

  case "CS":
    status = 3;
    console.log("NumberGot")
    break;

  case "Co":
    status = 4;
    console.log("Confirming")
    break;

  default:
    status = 0;
    break;
}
```

Comment: The issue may be due to `checkStatus` function

Comment: Hi, seems like some parts of your code snippet is missing. What does `checkStatus()` do and is it related with the `status` variable? _"Default code without the timings"_ - When the timings are relevant for the freezing issue, it could be a good idea to include them in the sample...

Comment: Well do you ever set running to false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it make with an interval.

```
setInterval(function(){
    fullStatus = checkStatus()
    switch (fullStatus.substring(0, 2)) {
      case "**":
        rolled = true;
        status = 1;
        console.log("Rolling")
        break;

      case "Ro":
        status = 2;
        console.log("Prepare Bets")
        break;

      case "CS":
        status = 3;
        console.log("NumberGot")
        break;

      case "Co":
        status = 4;
        console.log("Confirming")
        break;

      default:
        status = 0;
},1000);
```

This way, you can control the speed of your loop.

Answer (score 4):

At some point you have to set `running` to `false` in order to let the `while` loop end.

Otherwise the loop will keep running and browser freezes.

Note that `break;` exits the `switch` statement not the `while` loop.

---

Be aware that **as code execution is in progress the browser is unresponsive**.

If the termination of the `while` loop depends on user interaction then your code will never work (because the user cannot interact as the code execution is trapped inside the `while` loop).

I'm just guessing what you're trying to achieve...

If you have to **check status** as the user acts on the page then instead of a `while` loop you need a callback function that gets invoked upon user iteraction (ex. the click of a button) or gets triggered by a timer (see `setTimeout()`)

I don't go further because that would be beyond the scope of the question; I hope I pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Either set a interval to interleave executions are modify your code to be deterministic based on condition's. Currently it will loop till end of time, or at least till the ram burns, this implementation is known thread blocking because it hogs all available resources and as such do not reallocate in time for other applications to gabble. Since the state of the loop is dependent on the current state of running, then at some point in time, that state needs to  change. Because the break statement only exits a case condition, what you need to do is in every case set running to false, that is if that case statement permits it.